# Can't get client's network info from Silverlight...how about an applet?

Tags: java, silverlight, networking, dns, applet

I'm trying to create a Silverlight application that gathers network information, similar to that of running the command 'ipconfig /all' from the command line. I simply want to display the client's IP address, default gateway, and the DNS server(s). If the DNS server is pointed to their router, then I need a way to get the DNS server being used by the router. Any suggestions? I've looked a little into WMI but with no success. Silverlight is simply too compressed.

I have not done a lot in Java, but am wondering if perhaps a java applet would not be as restricted? I have a feeling I'll be running into the same sandbox issues.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> ..perhaps a java applet would not be as restricted?

Java applets have a comprehensive security environment that prevents many actions for any applet that is unsigned or untrusted.

For a signed and trusted applet, you would probably need to use natives to get some of that information. If the info. collection is blocked by the system itself or a firewall or similar, even the trusted applet will fail.

So probably more restricted, if anything.